# Dropping column conditionally in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to drop column if the error occurs. So, if the column exists then delete this column, else delete another column.

```scala
.foldLeft(mst) { (x, y) =>
  x
    .join(y.df, mergeWithTransformation(x, y), "cartesian")
    .drop(y.df("col1"))
}
```

I tried finding dropping with condition, but I didn't get anything. Any help? I am a newbie in scala development.

Comment: Can you clarify what would be the condition? What does it depend on?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that handles that separately from the `.foldLeft`; from your code snippet, I am assuming you are folding over a collection of data structures that have a data frame as a property and joining it to the original `mst` data frame.

```
def dropColumnConditionally(df: Dataframe, columnName: String, alternative: String): DataFrame = 
  if (df.columns.contains(columnName))
    df.drop(columnName) 
  else 
    df.drop(alternative)
```

and then you could use it:

```
.foldLeft(mst) { (x, y) => 
   val df = x.join(y.df, mergeWithTransformation(x, y), "cartesian")
   dropColumnConditionally(df, "col1", alternative = "col2")
}
```